# Using a Configuration file server-side in GWT

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, glassfish

I made a GWT App that use TCP/IP connections server side.

Now, I have harcoded the URL of the server that is used to connect:

```
private static final String URL = "https://localhost/ws";
```

I want to load this parameter from a config File like **TOMCAT/conf/webService.conf** or **TOMCAT/conf/webService.xml** but I can't find any propper way of doing this.

This app run in several servers and each server use a different WebService. I don't want to build a different app each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that using Google app Engine won't let me load config files on the server. I'm not using GAE so I just disabled it and now I can use Config files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put such configuration in an XML or properties file on the server side.  Then you can get this path at runtime from within a servlet

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/config");
File file = new File(path);
// Read as XML or properties file
```

Comment: But i'm not in a servlet. Is just a EntryPoint that draw HTML. I can't find getServletContext in any object out here.

Comment: Remember all the GWT client side code is translated to javascript. You cannot read a file on client filesystem using javascript. That is blocked due to security concerns.